# Make Facebook Page Plugin only scroll with 2 fingers on mobile

Tags: facebook

I have successfully embedded the facebook page plugin in my page, now I am trying to make it so the plugin only scrolls on mobile when 2 fingers are used, much like the google maps iframe embed. Don't even know where to start!

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=$siteFacebook?>" data-small-header="false" data-height='+fbHeight+' data-tabs="timeline" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/<?=$siteFacebook?>" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?=$siteFacebook?>"><?=$siteName?></a>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

where $siteFacebook is the id of my newsfeed

Comment: You start by accepting that this will be impossible, because the plugin renders as an iframe that loads its content from a different domain, so you have no scripting access to its content in any way, shape or form to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered if this was the case. What I am doing now is attempting to block interaction with the iframe via a transparent div above it in z-index, then to dismiss this div on either a double click or something. 
I will update this once I have a full fix in case it's useful to anyone else!

Answer (score 0):

As misorude pointed out, it's not possible to interact with the elements of an iframe, so I took a different tack. I overlaid the facebook iframe with a transparent div thus blocking any interaction with the iframe. on hover a message was displayed in the transparent div saying to 'click or tap to interact' (this also displayed on first touch interaction). On clicking the div (or second touch) it dropped the z-index of the transparent div behind the facebook iframe allowing the user to interact with the facebook iframe. 
Just thought I'd add my workaround solution in case it points someone in the right direction in the future.